# unable to delete entries after migration to new server

Tags: migration

After migrating from one server to another, I'm unable to delete entries.

I'm able to add new entries and change their status. But delete doesn't work.

The servers are identical (using digital ocean LAMP stack). I've checked my craft/server logs, I can't find any errors related to this.

Any suggestions as to where to look?

Comment: What does Craft do after you delete an entry specifically? Does it just say "error occurred" or just complete like nothing happened? I would try clearing Craft's caches if you haven't already done so.

Comment: There was no error message, no feed back at all. I would click delete and there would be no response.

I was able to workaround the problem by starting the migration over with a full snapshot of the original droplet. 

Something must have gone wrong in the manual migration I did (synchronizing files with git, and databases via phpmyadmin)